# Does Golink require decorations on symbol names?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm

Ok so I'm assembling code with NASM and linking with Golink. I have been using Windows API calls and C calls directly through the DLLs. For example, kernel32.dll for something like ExitProcess and msvcrt.dll for something like printf. However, when I try to use decorations like this, **_ExitProcess@4** or **_printf** golink complains about decorations and suggests using the **/mix** flag. When I use it Windows complains that the output file is not a valid win32 program. When I don't use decorations it works fine. Can anyone explain what's up?

Example:

```
extern printf
extern ExitProcess
;A bunch of code which isn't really important to this
```

Then my commands:

```
nasm -fwin32 test.asm
golink test.obj kernel32.dll msvcrt.dll /console /entry _start
```

Answer (score 2):

I use Nasm, but not in Windows so I'm not really familiar with GoLink. I think it adds the "decorations" internally. It may want the leading underscore. Nasm will add this to anything extern/global if you use "--prefix _" on the command line.

Reading the error message(s) carefully may give you a hint of what GoLink expects. Try it until trial > error. :)

Best,
Frank